# HTML with image and text side by side with fix height

Tags: html, css

I wanted to have multiple rows of images with text beside each images. After each rows, I want to have a horizontal line below. However, I am not able to get the height of each row to be consistent because the text can be 1 line or multiple lines. I could use "text-overflow: ellipsis" with max 2 text lines (to limit the text lines), but if there is only 1 text line, the height of each row would not be the same also.

Below are my codes:

```css
        .iconDetails {
          margin-left:4px;
          margin-right:8px;
          float:left; 
          height:70px;
          width:100px; 
        } 

        .container2 {
          width:100%;
          height:200;
          padding:1%;
        }
        .column2 h4{
          font-size: 15px; font-weight: 600;  
          margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
        .column2 p{
          font-size: 13px; font-weight: 300;  
          margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
```

```html
      <div class='container2'>
        <div>
            <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_v-U3K1sw9U/sddefault.jpg' class='iconDetails'>
        </div>  
      <div style='margin-left:10px;'>
      <h4>Title 1</h4>
              <p>Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text  </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
        <div class='container2'>
          <div>
              <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_v-U3K1sw9U/sddefault.jpg' class='iconDetails'>
          </div>  
        <div style='margin-left:10px;'>
        <h4>Title 2</h4>
            <p>Body 2.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text  </p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class='container2'>
        <div>
              <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_v-U3K1sw9U/sddefault.jpg' class='iconDetails'>
        </div>  
      <div style='margin-left:10px;'>
      <h4>Title 3</h4>
           <p>Body 3.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text...  </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
      <div class='container2'>
        <div>
              <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_v-U3K1sw9U/sddefault.jpg' class='iconDetails'>
        </div>  
      <div style='margin-left:10px;'>
      <h4>Title 4 .... Text Text Text Text........ Text .... Text .... Text ... Text...</h4>
           <p>Body 4.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text...  </p>
      </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you fine with the content text being scrolled if the texts are too long?

Comment: I would prefer to clip a long text to "..."

Comment: cannot you use `flexbox` or `grid` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this help?

I used flexbox to display the content side-by-side. I used `-webkit-line-clamp` to limit the number of lines then display the ellipses.

**UPDATE:** Added a javascript to check `header` and `paragraph` tag to `center-align` if the `offsetHeight` is greater than a set value. I used `20px` in this example.

```js
var h4s = document.getElementsByTagName("h4");
    var ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

    for (var i = 0; i < h4s.length; i++) {
        countLines(h4s[i]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
        countLines(ps[i]);
    }

    //count the lines per element
    function countLines(element) {


        if (element.offsetHeight > 20) {
            return;
        }

        element.style.textAlign = "center";
    }
```

```css
.iconDetails {
  height:70px;
  width:100px; 
} 

.container2 {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  padding:1%;
  display:flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.image-container {
  text-align: center;
  width:120px; 
}

.content-container {
  height: 100%;
  width:calc(100vw - 120px);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}

.content-container > h4 {
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.content-container > p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class='container2'>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_v-U3K1sw9U/sddefault.jpg' class='iconDetails'>
    </div>  
    <div class="content-container">
      <h4>Title 1</h4>
          <p>Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... 

          Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... 

        Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... TexBody 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... 

      Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. 

    Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text t ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text  </p>
      </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='container2'>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_v-U3K1sw9U/sddefault.jpg' class='iconDetails'>
    </div>  
    <div class="content-container">
      <h4>Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong Title is sooo loong </h4>
          <p>Body 1.. Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text... Text... Text ... Text ... Text  </p>
      </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='container2'>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_v-U3K1sw9U/sddefault.jpg' class='iconDetails'>
    </div>  
    <div class="content-container">
      <h4>Title is short</h4>
          <p>Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong Body is sooo loong </p>
      </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='container2'>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_v-U3K1sw9U/sddefault.jpg' class='iconDetails'>
    </div>  
    <div class="content-container">
      <h4>Title is kinda short Title is kinda short</h4>
          <p>Body is kinda long Body is kinda long Body is kinda long Body is kinda long Body is kinda long Body is kinda long</p>
      </div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class='container2'>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_v-U3K1sw9U/sddefault.jpg' class='iconDetails'>
    </div>  
    <div class="content-container">
      <h4>Title is short</h4>
          <p>Body is short</p>
      </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback with the solution. Yes, it does help, as each row sizes are now fixed.I have a feedback, using this code, the Title and Body are centre align if the Title or Body text is only using 1 row, therefore, can you add the code for the text to be top align? Others might benefit from this.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to apply a css `text-align: center;` for all the cases? Otherwise, it would need a javascript.

Comment: Anyway, I used a javascript here.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the solution and believe others would benefit from this as well!